# Matplotlib: no effect of set_data in imshow for the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a strange error which I can't fix without your help. After I set an image with `imshow` in matplotlib it stays the same all the time even if I change it with the method `set_data`. Just take a look on this example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def newevent(event):
    haha[1,1] += 1
    img.set_data(haha)
    print img.get_array()    # the data is change at this point
    plt.draw()

haha = np.zeros((2,2))
img = plt.imshow(haha)
print img.get_array()        # [[0,0],[0,0]]
plt.connect('button_press_event', newevent)
plt.show()
```

After I plot it, the method `set_data` doesn't change anything inside the plot. Can someone explain me why?

**EDIT**

Just added a few lines to point out what I actually want to do.
I want to redraw the data after I press a mouse button. I don't want to delete the whole figure, because it would be stupid if only one thing changes.

Comment: Just one an edge would have an other color.

Comment: Where are you calling `newevent`?

Answer (score 25):

The problem is because you have not updated the pixel scaling after the first call.

When you instantiate `imshow`, it sets `vmin` and `vmax` from the initial data, and never touches it again. In your code, it sets both `vmin` and `vmax` to 0, since your data, `haha = zeros((2,2))`, is zero everywhere.

Your new event should include autoscaling with `img.autoscale()` , or explicitly set new scaling terms by setting `img.norm.vmin/vmax` to something you prefer.

The function to set the new `vmin` and `vmax` is:

```
img.set_clim(vmin=new_vim, vmax=new_vmax)
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this give you the output you expect?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

haha = np.zeros((2,2))
img = plt.imshow(haha)
print img.get_array()        # [[0,0],[0,0]]
haha[1,1] += 1

img.set_data(haha)    
img = plt.imshow(haha)       # <<------- added this line  
print img.get_array()        # [[0,0],[0,1]]
plt.show()
```

When I display the plot twice (once before the change to `haha`, and at the end), it does change.

Comment: @PateToni I don't see where you are calling `newevent` -- did my answer not solve your problem?

Comment: It will solve it, but it will force an additional plot. Which consume more and more memory every time you plot a new `imshow`.

Comment: @PateToni I see what you are saying. What platform are you running this under? Under Windows 7 with v 2.7.2 I `newevent` never gets called (even with your code update).

Comment: I run it under Linux. And it works okay, but the plot doesn't change.

Comment: @PateToni I guess I won't be able to help. I just ran it under Linux too (Kernel 2.6.32 Ubuntu 10.04LTS) with Python 2.6.5 and if I put any print statements into `newevent` and run your code, none of the `print`s shows which means the function never gets call. Perhaps there's more required for the code to run?

Comment: Thanks anyway. I don't know why it isn't running on your machine. I have a newer version of Python and Ubuntu , but it's strange that this don't work for you. I'm doing this event-thing for years and never had some problems before, just never try to update the plotted data.